# How do I pickle a file containing strings?

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to parse a log file with records like :

```
Apr 29 06:56:48 example-server sshd[38254]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=123.183.209.132  user=root
Apr 29 06:56:50 example-server CRON[33299]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 29 06:56:50 example-server sshd[38254]: Failed password for root from 123.183.209.132 port 55181 ssh2
Apr 29 06:56:56 example-server sshd[38254]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed password for root from 123.183.209.132 port 55181 ssh2]
Apr 29 06:56:59 example-server sshd[38254]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]
Apr 29 06:56:59 example-server sshd[38254]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=123.183.209.132  user=root
```

I am trying to pickle the file

```
with open('auth.log', 'rb') as logs:
    db = pickle.load(logs)
```

I am getting the error message:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Is `auth.log` pickled, or is just plain text?

Comment: *pickle* is work with an object, not a text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pickle several .txt files into one pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884903/how-to-pickle-several-txt-files-into-one-pickle)

Comment: I don't understand. `pickle.load` is to *un*pickle a file. Pickling is when you *create* the file, from your Python objects.

Comment: @CalderWhite it is just plain text.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That was a noob mistake. Sorry about that. but even 

`pickle_out = open('s.pickle'.'wb')
pickle.dump(file,pickle_out)
`
doesn't work. I think since as mentioned by @CalderWhite the file is a regular text file and not a python object, we can't pickle it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seams like your log file wasn't created by the pickle module.

> The pickle module implements binary protocols for serializing and
>   de-serializing a Python object structure. “Pickling” is the process
>   whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and
>   “unpickling” is the inverse operation [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

So a better approach might be loading your log file and parsing it as text. For example you could select all fatal errors using something like:

```
db = []
with open('auth.log', 'r') as logs:
    for log in logs: #for each line
        if 'fatal' in log:
            db.append(log)
```

You can find more about log file parsing [here](https://pythonicways.wordpress.com/2016/12/20/log-file-parsing-in-python/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks a lot for the log parsing tutorial. That helped me a ton.