# How to import a txt file into i pickle file?

Tags: python

am new to Python and working a bit on pickle files.
I have already a pickle file called training.pickle and a txt file called danish.txt
I would like to import the danish.txt to the training.pickle file but i don't know how to do ?

I have tried some thing but am sure its wrong :-)

```
import pickle
file1=open('danish.txt','r')
file2=open('training.pickle','r')
obj=[file1.read(), file2.read()]
outfile.write("obj,training.pickle")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884903/how-to-pickle-several-txt-files-into-one-pickle/6897610

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pickle several .txt files into one pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884903/how-to-pickle-several-txt-files-into-one-pickle)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about pickle but if you're just trying to add the data from "danish.txt" to the pickle file you should be able to just open the .txt, store the data in a variable, and then write the data in the pickle.
To demonstrate my thinking:

```
f = open("danish.txt", "r+")
data = f.read()
output = data
f.close() #this reads the .txt file
```

and then afterward you'd write "output" into the pickle file via whatever method you use to write a string variable to a pickle file.

P.S. as I said I don't know much about pickle, but if it works anything like writing to a .txt you'd have to change the r to a w because r means opening it in read mode. If its just reading it can't write, or atleast that's how it works with .txts. Also, if there's no particular reason why you're using a pickle to store data, why not just use a .txt?